# I import image in gcp dicom store, but on my pubsub topic assigned dicom store is not publishing message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-health, google-cloud-healthcare

**steps**

I create

1. dicom dataset
2. inside dataset dicom store
3. pubsub topic for dicom store

**Issue**

I am trying to import dcm image to dicom store from storage bucket operation is showing `Success` in dicom-store operations but message is not publishing on assigned topic.

*Healthcare and Pubsub API are Enable and granted permissions.*

Comment: Hello, have you followed any tutorial/documentation? Waiting for your response.

Comment: yes. i follow this document
https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/dicom-connect-pacs#kubectl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DICOM API will only send PubSub notifications when images are inserted using [StoreInstances](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/dicomweb#storing_a_dicom_instance). Sending Pub/Sub notifications while importing from GCS isn't supported at the moment. I'll make sure the documentation is updated to make this clear.

Comment: thanks it worked. message got published on pubsub.@dzelemba